# how to order the column values from initial to final with data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this,

```
create table Input_Table(id int, [year] varchar(100),initial int,final int)

insert into Input_table values(1,'2017',1,11)
insert into Input_table values(2,'2017',8,11)
insert into Input_table values(3,'2017',3,33)
insert into Input_table values(4,'2016',6,44)
insert into Input_table values(5,'2016',6,44)
insert into Input_table values(6,'2017',6,44)
insert into Input_table values(7,'2016',4,8)
insert into Input_table values(8,'2017',2,8)
```

I need to get the output based on the requirement shown in the pic [image]

Comment: select distinct initial from Input_table
order by initial

select distinct year from Input_table

Comment: select 'Change from' distinct initial 'to' final as [data],
count(year) as '2016', count(year) as '2017'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Acheive your given output, you can follow this;

```
Select 
    DISTINCT(
        'Change From '+ Cast(initial AS Varchar(10))+' to '+Cast(final AS Varchar(10))
        ) AS DATA
    ,SUM(Case When year=2017 Then 1 Else 0 END) AS [2017]
    ,SUM(Case When year=2016 Then 1 Else 0 END) AS [2016]
 From Input_table 
 Group By initial, final
 ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

NOTE:- If you will give your real use of it. Then might be i can suggest, better solution then this.

Answer (score 0):

[ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause in the SELECT. And also [SQL Server specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

```
SELECT * FROM Input_table ORDER BY initial
```

Comment: I need the [data],[2016],[2017] columns as well in the output, please check the screenshot. its not that simple